# Como proyectar una variable de una pagina a otra de php?

Tags: php, html, css

bueno el dilema que tengo es que tengo un login que su codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('location: index.php');
    }

    $error = '';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $clave = $_POST['clave'];
        $clave = hash('sha512', $clave);

        try{
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login_tuto', 'root', '');
            }catch(PDOException $prueba_error){
                echo "Error: " . $prueba_error->getMessage();
            }

        $statement = $conexion->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = :usuario AND clave = :clave'
        );

        $statement->execute(array(
            ':usuario' => $usuario,
            ':clave' => $clave
        ));

        $resultado = $statement->fetch();

        if ($resultado !== false){
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
            header('location: principal.php');

        }else{
            $error .= '<i>El usuario o la contrasena esta incorrecto</i>';
        }
    }

require 'frontend/login-vista.php';
?>
```

Lo que quiero es que al iniciar sesion tome el nombre del usuario ingresado en el login y este remplace el texto iniciar sesion y ponga el nombre de ese usuario dentro de otra pagina. Pero no tengo el conocimiento de como unir las paginas y asi pasar el nombre de el usuario dentro de la variable.La pagina la cual he intentado es : PD: Es un prototipo

```
<html>
<head>
    </head>
    <body background=https://pic.001all.com/Wallpaper/Galaxy%20S9/02/Samsung%20Galaxy%20S9%20Wallpaper%20for%20sf69%20purple%20blue%20hippo%20lake%20gradation%20hazy%201440%20x%202960.jpg>
       <style> 
         .bye{
            display: block;
            margin-top: 80px;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }  
           </style>
 <div class="bye">

        <?php
     $usuario=$_GET["usuario"];
   $resultado=$_GET['resultado'];
          $cerrar= 'Aqui cerrare secion';
 if($resultado !== false){
        echo $cerrar;}
        else{
        echo $usuario;}
            ?>
        </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

(Ya he intentado con el include pero tengo uan parte en el codigo la cual si el usuario inicia exitosamente lo manda a mi pagina de inicio y al utilizar este metodo lo unico que hace es que me redireccion a el inicio).

Muchas gracias de antemano...

Comment: Precisamente para eso sirven las variables de sesión. De hecho ya estas cargando en la variable `$_SESSION['usuario']` el nombre del usuario. Si en el otro script PHP invocas esa variable, va a tener lo que quieres. Obviamente tienes que iniciar el otro script con `session_start();`

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, para pasar el nombre de una pagina a otra  se hace con las variable de session. El contenido lo quieres colocar dentro del div que aparece en la vista

Comment: aeportugal entonces si no mal te entendi primeramente pondre el session_start(); pero como invocare a la varible que segun yo tenia que usar el GET. Perdon por mi ignorancia...

Comment: Si Yoel lo quiero colocar dentro del div pero solo estaba probando.